Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11 not working on flutter
Im using VS Code with flutter.
Wehn trying to build appbundle for android to publish the app, im getting the error:
    * What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11.
      Your current JDK is located in /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home
      You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


After some research, I saw many people saying to follow  Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Build Tools → Gradle → *Gradle JDK, but I wasn't able to find de Grade JDK on Android Studio
How can I fix this?

You have couple options here:

Update Android Studio.

Explanation: Since Flutter found JDK installation from Android Studio, it looks like Android Studio itself is bit outdated, since recent versions are being shipped with JDK 21.

Set JDK for Flutter separately.

Flutter can be configured to use separate JDK installation. For this, command flutter config --jdk-dir="path_to_jdk". If you have an separate installations of JDK (maybe with brew install jdk@17 or similar), just put it's path to command flutter config and Flutter will use it and will stop depending on JDK from Android Studio.
